# Curl effect on Titanium Android/Ios App

Tags: titanium-mobile

I am new in titanium platform. I want to know how to make curl effect titanium android and ios. Please provide me solution if it is possible.

Comment: What is a "curl effect"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know Android does not have such effect built-in to it's OS. But iPhone does.
You can make a curl transition between two windows by using the code:

```
//create new window first with Ti.UI.createWindow({});
window.open({
 modal:true,
 modalTransitionStyle:Ti.UI.iPhone.MODAL_TRANSITION_STYLE_PARTIAL_CURL,
 modalStyle:presentation,
 navBarHidden:Ti.UI.iPhone.MODAL_PRESENTATION_CURRENT_CONTEXT
});
```